# How to NOT do a reduceRegion from empty image collections?

Tags: google-earth-engine, conditional, reduceregion

I am collecting the Kelvin temperature of a field from Landsat imagery for October for a period of 20 years.  Due to clouds, there are some images that are being removed by my pruning, leading to certain years containing no images for that month-year.  (this is not the problem)

I have a Feature Collection, where each feature has a `year` property that tells me which year I should reduceRegion for.

I map a function to "extract" the mean of the temperature from the imageCollection of the year that is contained in the year property.  The problem lies when I try to trap with `ee.Algorithms.If()` for an empty image collection once it is filtered to the year in question. Using `reduceRegion()` on an empty collection creates an error.
However, no matter how I try, the `reduceRegion()` always gets evaluated, even if it should be ignored as it is in the area of the function that will not be evaluated if the collection is of `.size()` `0`.

```
myBlockCollection
```

is my Feature Collection containing 20 features with a property of "year" for the year I am interested in filtering my images to.

```
selectedPass
```

is my pruned image collection that only contains the October images that pass the "QC" test and will contain no more than 1 image per year, but could contain no images for a specific year.

```
var addKelvintoFeature = function(myFeature){

   var myBlock = ee.Feature(myFeature);
   var theYear = ee.Number.parse(myBlock.get("year"));  


   var thermalBlockThisYearMean = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(selectedPass
     .filterDate(ee.Date.fromYMD(theYear,10,1),ee.Date.fromYMD(theYear,11,1)).size(),
     selectedPass                   
     .filterDate(ee.Date.fromYMD(theYear,10,1),ee.Date.fromYMD(theYear,11,1)).size()
     .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),myBlock.geometry())
     .getNumber("Kelvin")           // if size is not 0, we do this
     ,-1));                         // if size is 0, we assign -1 so that we end with a negative number
      

    
   var thermalBlockSeriesMin = selectedPass.map(
     function(image){
       return ee.Feature(null,  {meanKelvin:image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),myBlock.geometry()).getNumber("Kelvin")});
     })
     .aggregate_min("meanKelvin");       //This works fine every time


   var th1 = thermalBlockThisYearMean.divide(thermalBlockSeriesMin);

   return myBlock.set("th1",th1);

    };  


    return ee.FeatureCollection(myBlockCollection).map(addKelvintoFeature);

 };
```

When I replace the `reduceRegion()` with a simple `.size()` there is no issue with the If statement, as that does not produce an error.

Comment: An Idea might be to do it the other way around: Get all the years that are available in the Image Collection and only map over the years that are available. In that way you don't need to rely on a (in Earth Engine) cumbersome if statement

Comment: Good Point.  Let me think of how to go around it.  I guess create a years list that only contains the valid years.  I'll give it a try and come back to see if it works.

Comment: As you suggested, I have created a list of years containing only the years where I have images and using  ```var yearsAvailable = selectedPass.aggregate_array("system:time_start").map(function(time_start){return ee.Date(time_start).get("year")})
```   and this is info is added to my features (with only existing features for valid years).  However, the error still persists in the ```reduceRegion()```   When I run the ```size()``` debug I do get a "1" so there is an image.

Comment: Just solved it.....  needed to add ```.first()``` so that it reduced to an image and not a collection with 1 image....  Thanks JonasV.  Please give your comment as an answer so that I can credit you for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve this would be to do it the other way around: Get all the years that are available in the Image Collection and only map over the years that are available.

That way you don't need to rely on a (in Earth Engine) cumbersome if statement.

Comment: Thanks.  Restricted the years with the following code ```var yearsAvailable = selectedPass.aggregate_array("system:time_start").map(function(time_start){return ee.Date(time_start).get("year")})```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't runnable to check, but you can probably use `imageCollection.cast` to give all images in the original collection all the expected bands.  When there's no image there, you'll have completely masked bands for that year.  But that way, the reduceRegion will always succeed, even if there's no data for that year.

Comment: Thanks Noel, I believe the issue with ReduceRegion had to do with the fact that my ```filterDate()``` gave me a collection.  I didn't realise this till way after JonasV comments and I tried his suggestion (and still had the same error).  solved with a simple ```.first()```